Why doesn't Python's type checking raise an error when there is a mismatch with a TypeAlias?
Here's a trivial example:
"""Test typing problems."""

from typing import TypeAlias

Verb: TypeAlias = str


def concats_string(base: Verb) -> str:
    # Trivial example - should just append to the passed in value
    return " ".join([base, "World"])


greeting: str = "Hello"
print(concats_string(greeting))

I can't get MyPy, PyRight, or pytype to raise an error about the function call.
(Indeed, the join function should be flagged too...)
I'm guessing this is expected behaviour, since different implementations don't complain - but what am I missing here?
Isn't this the point of a TypeAlias and exactly what a type checker should flag?

I think typing.NewType would be more appropriate for this

I do not understand. Verb is an alias for str and greeting is a str. There is no mismatch, it is the same type.

See related: Type hints: Is it a bad practice to alias primitive data types? It's not really bad practice, but what you seem to be expecting is not what TypeAlias is for.

Thanks all - yes, this does seem to be what's expected after re-reading the docs.
I've been able to get the desired behaviour with NewType.

It's the expected behaviour. As read in the documentation, the type alias "... will be treated equivalently by static type checkers".
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases
The documentation is always a good starting point!
